# Problem with calling nightmare multiple times with help of vo, first time work, second time always fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am coding a program that can check that is a page able to be loaded with help of nightmare and vo. 
https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vo
I declared two generators,run1 and run2,that nightmare will goto the URL given and wait for the selectors in the webpage to be loaded. 
run1 is a success case, console will log 'Loading page is loaded'.
run2 is a fail case, console will log 'Not found'.
I declare one more generator wrapAllResult in order to call run1 and run2 in order.

In wrapAllResult, if I only call run1, it shows the correct result.
if I only call run2, it shows the correct result.(log 'Not found')
But, if I call run1 and run2 together, only the first one will be run successfully. if I put run1 first, then it will log 'Loading page is loaded' but 'Not found' will not be shown. if I put run2 first, then it performs oppositely.

```js
var run1 = function*() {
  yield nightmare
    .goto('https://www.hkbn.net/personal/home/tc/landing')
    .wait('#root') // Wait for landing page
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Not Found')
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Landing page is loaded.');
    })
  yield nightmare.end();
  return null;
}

var run2 = function*() {
  yield nightmare
    .goto('https://www.hkbn.net/personal/home/tc/landing')
    .wait('#rodfsdfdsffsfdsfdsfot') // Wait for landing page
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Landing page is loaded.');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Not Found')
    })

  yield nightmare.end();
  return null;
}

var wrapAllResult = function*() {
  yield vo(run1)();
  yield vo(run2)();
}

vo(wrapAllResult)();
```

I want the result of run1 and run2 can both be show in order.

Comment: You need to use `async/await` here.

Comment: according to my research on Google, vo must be used with nightmare.js, I am not sure why, I still can not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem is cause by the ":" character in the time string. /, >, <, |, :, & are characters that will cause the issue.